# How does this recursive algorithm navigate through all the possible subsets of a list?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, subset

I am trying to go through this algorithm in java and line by line to see how it figures out every possible way to divide a linkedlist into two subsets. The goal is to identify one subset whose sum equals the sum of the remaining subset. I see how it arrives at a solution, but I don't understand how it moves backwards to get there. First, I see that the sum of the first four numbers are considered, and compared to 0. Then, the sum first three numbers are compared to the sum of the final number. That's where I get lost. How does it navigate through all the possibilities recursively?

```
public class Target {
/*--------------LINKED LIST------------------*/
private Node head;
private Node tail;

public void add(int obj) {
    if(head == null){
        head = new Node(obj);
        tail = head;
    } else {
        tail.next = new Node(obj);
        tail = tail.next;
    }
}
class Node {
    public Node next;
    public int item;

    public Node(int item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
/*--------------LINKED LIST------------------*/

public Target() {
    head = null;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Target list = new Target();

    list.add(4);
            list.add(5);
            list.add(6);
            list.add(7);

    System.out.println(list.recursiveSolution(list));
}

public boolean recursiveSolution(Target list) {
        return subsetSum(list.head, 0, 0);
}

private boolean subsetSum(Node node, long sumOne, long sumTwo) {

    if (node == null) {
            System.out.println(Long.toString(sumOne) + ", " + Long.toString(sumTwo));  
        return sumOne == sumTwo;  //base case
    }

    return subsetSum(node.next, sumOne + node.item, sumTwo) || 
           subsetSum(node.next, sumOne, sumTwo + node.item);
}
}
```

Comment: Who wrote this code and are you certain it is correct?

Comment: Doesn't look like it goes through all combinations.  What happens if you try values 4, 6, 5, 7 instead of 4, 5, 6, 7?

Answer (score 0):

Look at subsetSum. What it does is that it tries to add the next node to either sumOne or sumTwo. If there is no next node it returns true if the sums are equal.

To answer what I think your question is. When it calls subsetSum recursively it adds a new function call on the call stack. When the call is done it will resume from that point.

You can proof that the code goes through all combinations because for and combination you can think of you can construct a series of calls that will yield that combination.

However this only happens if no solution was found. Once you have found a combination that yields true in the final check because of the short-circuit property of || the code will simply return through the stack and return true, skipping all the other combinations.